# Probability of friends picking the same set of numbers

Tags: probability

Let's say me and my friend both pick 3 numbers between 0-9 inclusive randomly. There cannot be repeats. What are the odds that 1 of our numbers matches? Odds of 2 of them matching? Odds that all 3 match? The selections by me and my friend are independent.

So I figured that the total number of combinations of 3 numbers is 10*9*8 = 720. So for all 3 numbers to match it should be 1/720 odds. To figure out the odds for one of them matching and for 2 of them to match is where I get tripped up. How do I calculate number of ways 1 of them can match without including the scenario where 2 of the numbers match?

Please let me know if I need to clarify anything. Thank you

Comment: If you pick $(7,1,2)$ and your friend picks $(2,7,1)$, do you consider that as all three of them matching? That is, does order matter?

Comment: order does not matter

Comment: What if the order is important? Does this change the answer? I used permutations instead of combination following the accepted answer, is that right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Think about it like this. Suppose that you choose your three numbers first before your friend does. Then we can partition that $10$ available numbers (from $0$ to $9$) into $3$ "good" numbers and $7$ "bad" numbers.

- The probability that your friend chooses exactly $3$ good numbers and $0$ bad numbers is:
  $$
  \dfrac{\binom{3}{3}\binom{7}{0}}{\binom{10}{3}} = \frac{1}{120}
  $$
- The probability that your friend chooses exactly $2$ good numbers and $1$ bad number is:
  $$
  \dfrac{\binom{3}{2}\binom{7}{1}}{\binom{10}{3}} = \frac{21}{120} = \frac{7}{40}
  $$
- The probability that your friend chooses exactly $1$ good number and $2$ bad numbers is:
  $$
  \dfrac{\binom{3}{1}\binom{7}{2}}{\binom{10}{3}} = \frac{63}{120} = \frac{21}{40}
  $$

Comment: I like this answer a lot. It is simple to understand

Comment: What is the notation used here? I can't figure out how e.g. (10 3) gives 120. Does anyone have a reference? Thanks.

Comment: @JamieBullock: These are combinations. In this case:
$$
\binom{10}{3} = \frac{10!}{7!3!} = \frac{10 \cdot 9 \cdot 8}{3 \cdot 2} = 10 \cdot 3 \cdot 4 = 120
$$
See here for more details: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combination

Comment: Thanks @Adriano

Answer (score 1):

How many ways are there that 2 but not 3 of the numbers match?  Call the numbers that match $a_1, a_2$, and $a_3$.  Call the numbers that don't match $b_1 .. b_7$.  How many ways can you generate $\{a_?, a_?, b_?\}$?  There are $3$ ways to pick the $a$ values ($\{a_1, a_2\}, \{a_1, a_3\}, \{a_2, a_3\}$) and $7$ ways to pick the $b$ values, so $21$ total unordered ways to pick 2 but not 3 matches.

Similarly, how many ways are the that 1 but not 2 of the numbers match?  There you are creating $\{a_?, b_?, b_?\}$.  There are $3$ ways to choose the $a$ value, and $7 \choose{2}$ ways to choose the $b$ values, so total $3\cdot {7 \choose 2} = 63$ ways to create those unordered matches.

How many ways are there to choose it so no numbers match?  There you are creating $\{b_?, b_?, b_?\}$, so you have ${7 \choose 3} = 35$ ways.

How many ways are there to pick total?  $21 + 63 + 35 + 1 = 120$.  So the respective probabilities are ${21 \over 120}, {63 \over 120}, {35 \over 120}$, and ${1 \over 120}$.

Comment: Thank you! This makes sense